# Error: expected expression before '%' token

Tags: c, string, printing, compiler-errors, representation

I'm not sure what is causing this error in this line of code

```
printf(%d=12 * %d + %d "\n", a, &b, &c); }
```

The error states "expected expression before '%' token" but I'm not sure which of the string representations or "%"'s its referring too.

Comment: just when posting on SO, you can see that the code is wrong: the format string is bicolor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misplaced double quotes. There's no format string, since the first character after `(` is not `"`, but `%`.

```
printf("%d=12 * %d + %d\n", a, b, c);
```

As BLUPIXY correctly points out, you should also avoid printing addresses `&b`, `&c` as integers with `%d`. If you really want to print addresses, you must use `%p` with ptr-to-void, i.e. this:

```
printf("%d=12 * %p + %p\n", a, (void *)&b, (void *)&c);
```

It would be helpful to see the declarations for a, b and c.

Comment: maybe, Remove `&`

Comment: `%d` require `int`, not pointer (if pointer, UB, right?).

Comment: whatever, but I'm not sure this question deserves an answer. It's just a typo.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Got it. My mind was auto-converting `&` to `*` ;-)

Comment: Also `12 * %p + %p` as 12 * pointer + pointer is invalid pointer arithmetic.